# Cmake qxt how to use find package

Tags: cmake, libqxt

I have a Qt based program with Qxt library. Previously I used the default Qt .pro file to configure the header and library directories, and everything is OK. Now I want to immigrate the thing to build with Cmake, it seems OK to include line by line in the Cmake file. But I saw this:

https://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/src/a5a0614e4cc4/features/QxtConfig.cmake

Qxt is not built with Cmake as a perquisite. I was wondering how to use this file to find the Qxt like Cmake find qt as a package?

Julio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the top level of your directory tree for your project, add a `cmake` folder with a `Modules` subfolder:

```
your_project_dir/
    |-src/
    |-cmake/
    |   |-Modules/
    |-CMakeLists.txt
```

Put the `QxtConfig.cmake` file in `cmake/Modules/`.  In your `CMakeLists.txt`, add the following lines:

```
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/")
INCLUDE(${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}/QxtConfig.cmake)
```

This will run the code in the `QxtConfig.cmake` file.

Note that if the file were called `FindQxt.cmake`, you could call `FIND_PACKAGE(Qtx)` instead of `INCLUDE(${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}/QxtConfig.cmake)`.

**Note**

Of course, you don't need to do the whole `cmake/Modules/` thing. You could just put the `QxtConfig.cmake` file next to `CMakeLists.txt` and omit everything about `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`, but it's good practice to have a `Modules` directory because the number of extra module files can grow in a big project.